# Configure haskell-language-server to see generated proto-lens modules

Tags: haskell, protocol-buffers, haskell-language-server

I've got a fairly stock `stack` based project that uses `proto-lens-setup` to generate some Haskell code from some `.proto` files.  I'm using `haskell-language-server` with wonderful success in emacs for everything *except* when my code imports any of the `Proto.Myproto` modules.  It can't find them and thusly can't properly check the files I'm editing.

The project builds perfectly, but I'd like to have the `lsp` working.  It's very helpful!

I get errors highlighted anytime my code uses an identifier from the `proto-lens`-generated code.   I've tried looking into `hie-bios` configurations but didn't see anything obvious to put in a manual config to make it work.  I don't normally have a manual `hie-bios` config.